# Cannot trap 8004020f error in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, error-handling, asp-classic

I cannot trap the 8004020f error generated by a script in Visual Basic (CDOSYS component).
I used the "**on error resume next**", it traps all errors except for this one.
This error is generated in this situation:
- the mailserver I use for sending hosts mailboxes belonging to @mydomain.abc
- I try to send mail to nonexistant@mydomain.abc

That is, if I try to send an email to a non-existant user of a domain hosted on the same mailserver used for sending, this action causes the error.

This is (almost) impossible to catch!! What can I do? I have a lot of databases and my old non-existant address is found in hundredths of tables and databases!
Thanks

Comment: Instead of trying to hide the error (which is actually all `OERN` really does) you should fix the cause of the error. [This article](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/email/why-does-cdo-message-give-me-8004020f-errors.html) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Put in the following in order to find the real error code, which is a decimal number. For example, 13=type mismatch.

```
<%
response.write("err.number=" & err.number & "<br>")
%>
```

OR...

I looked at my own stuff and found this:

```
Select Case err.Number
    Case -2147220973
        strRet = " Failure to Send Report Message - Server Not Found" & vbCrLf & " Error: " & err.Number & " - " &  err.Description
    Case -2147220975
        strRet = " Failure to Send Report Message - Server Authentication Failed" & vbCrLf & " Error: " & err.Number & " - " & err.Description
    Case Else
        strRet = " Failure to Send Report Message - Error: " & err.Number & " - " & err.Description
End Select
```